# How to have a conversation with a bot?

Tags: python, bots, python-telegram-bot

I want to send a [python telegram bot](https://python-telegram-bot.org) a specific command that causes the bot to respond with a request for more information and listen for another message containing that extra information.

For instance:

- I send `/add` the bot responds: `ok, tell me your torrent link`.
- I send the bot another message with the torrent link and the bot saves it into a Python variable for further use.

Comment: You'll need a ConversationHandler for that. See https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would look into [ConversationHandler](https://pythonhosted.org/python-telegram-bot/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html?module-telegram.ext.conversationhandler)